# Determine if ArcGISDynamicMapServiceLayer is from a Tiled Map Service in ESRI JavaScript API

Tags: arcgis-server, arcgis-maps-sdk-javascript, dynamic-layer

For some of our JavaScript mapping applications, we load a Tiled Map Service as a ArcGISDynamicMapServiceLayer. When we use the PrintTask and want to print a map at a scale in between the tiled map scales, this works great.

For a map Table of Contents widget, however, I need a way to determine if an ArcGISDynamicMapServiceLayer has been loaded from a tiled or dynamic map service. Any recommendations?

I'm using ArcGIS JavaScript API v.3.6.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You could try sending a JSON request to the map service URL of the layer and checking the singleFusedMapCache property of the JSON object that's returned - a value of true would indicate it's coming from a tiled service and false would indicate it's a dynamic service.